# how to get src id

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="2" class="dsi" onmousedown="test(2);" ondrop="checkImg('2');dropIt(event,2);" ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
    <img src="2.gif" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragIt(event,2);" onmousedown="test(1)" id="pic2" />
</div>
```

I want to get `src` of `img` using javascript. How can I do it ?(i wonto get img id using div id.i mean using div id as 2 then result is pic2.)

Answer (score 1):

Using JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("pic2").getAttribute("src");
```

Using Jquery

```
$("#pic2").attr('src')
```

For the second question you asked in comment on how do we get in case of a loop.

I am assuming your id are like pic1, pic2, .... , pic9

```
for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++)    {
    var picId =  'pic' + i;
    document.getElementById(picId).getAttribute("src");
}
```

Comment: i wont to put java script code in for loop how could i do it. my dive ids are 1 to 9

Comment: thanks for the help.but i wont find img id using div id.because i try to create image puzzle using java script.i try to use this method to check final result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `src` of the image then

```
var imgSrc= document.getElementById("pic2").src;
```

Comment: id '2' is a `div`. did you mean id `pic2`

Comment: i wont to get pic2 as an answer

Comment: @A_J you can use it `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].id;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var imgSrc= document.getElementById("pic2").src;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

jQuery method :

```
var youtubeimgsrc = $('#pic2').attr('src');
```

javascript method :

```
var youtubeimgsrc = document.getElementById("pic2").src
```